# Virtual Assistant deployment error "Could not create Dispatch app. Review the log for more information."

Tags: azure, botframework

i am trying to deploy the Virtual Assistant solution into Azure. i am getting error "Could not create Dispatch app. Review the log for more information." as a result Dispatch app not created in Luis only General app created and cognitivemodels.json file also blank in the solution.

please correct me where i need to correct.

> Creating resource group ...
>   Validating Azure deployment ...
>   Deploying Azure services (this could take a while)...
>   Updating appsettings.json ...
>   Deploying cognitive models ...
>   Initializing dispatch model ...
>   Parsing General LU file ...
>   Deploying General LUIS app ...
>   Setting LUIS subscription key ...
>   Adding General app to dispatch model ...
>   Parsing Chitchat LU file ...
>   Deploying Chitchat QnA kb ...
>   Adding Chitchat kb to dispatch model ...
>   Parsing Faq LU file ...
>   Deploying Faq QnA kb ...
>   Adding Faq kb to dispatch model ...
>   Creating dispatch model...
>   ! Could not create Dispatch app. Review the log for more information.
>   ! Log: C:\Users\SGPAMIDIS\source\repos\MyAssistant1\MyAssistant1\MyAssistant1\Deployment\Scripts..\deploy_cognitive_models_log.txt
>   Summary of the deployed resources:
>   - Resource Group: TA-djnsjfnjfn-001
>   - Bot Web App: MyAssistant1-vydytja

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. How did you deploy (PowerShell, Portal,...) ?

Comment: i used Power shell with below deployment statement:

Comment: .\Deployment\Scripts\deploy.ps1 -name "MyAssistant1" -location "westeurope" -appPassword "MyAssistant1" -luisAuthoringKey "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" -luisAuthoringRegion westeurope -resourceGroup "TA-XXXXXXX-XXX-001"

Comment: Did you also post [this](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/issues/2525)? Did you inspect the log file? You are using a powershell file deploy.ps1 did you create it youself? Oterwise check if there are no updates.

Comment: yes i am the one posted this #2525. anyway i need to help to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: Can you attach the log file?